# How to prevent an uploaded file to Google Drive to be downloaded on sync

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am creating a sync service to my Android App that uses Google Drive appdata folder to store some files.

When I sync, I look for changes after my last sync using the `ChangeList.getLargestChangeId()`.

The problem is that when I upload a new file, since this ID changes after any change, the file is downloaded on the next sync.

How do I work around it?

Thanks.